# TP Link - data statistics resets after modem restart

Tags: reboot, modem, statistics, resource-usage

I have TP Link - TL-WR841N / TL-WR841ND.

I want to track data usage per device on monthly basis. I have enabled data statistics on my modem. But the statistics are getting cleared after modem restart.

How can I persist it even if modem is restarted?

Comment: If this model supports logging to remote syslog server, then setup any unix based computer and forward routers log to it

Comment: @Alex: Yes, the model supports sending system log over mail but doesn't support sending the data statistics over mail...Can I construct data usage stats from router log?

Comment: I meant not sending log over mail but to remote `syslog`. As about constructing usage stats from router log, it is a different question, but anything can be parsed if log containing data you want  and build report you want base on such data

Comment: @Alex Seems my router doesn't support logging to remote syslog server :(

Comment: Well, if you good on scripting, you can parse emails that your router can send periodically. Harder, but still posible

Answer (score 0):

If the default TP-Link firmware only supports statistics in RAM, a possible alternative is to install [OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd), and then add a bit of scripting to either store statistics on flash (but be aware flash write cycles are limited), or send the statistics somewhere else (remote syslog, mail, whatever you fancy) where you can track them.

Infos about options for bandwidth monitoring on OpenWRT are [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/bwmon), and googling finds tutorialss, howto's etc.

Comment: I am relatively new to this topic. When you say "add a bit of scripting", do you mean download the source code and modify it or does it provide some hook-points to add scripts. Can you please point me to some document. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I think it's "sort of both": OpenWRT has [packages](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/packages) like any other Linux distro, and some are for bandwidth measurement statistics. Those would provide hooks. Or you can write your own shell scripts. Or, or ... There's lots of ways to do it, and I can't recommend a "best way". In your place, I'd read through the options, google a bit, and try out a few till you find something you like. Maybe that's a new question for the software recommendations stack exchange.